# Handling max URL lengths

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, url

I make a request to a server which builds a URL and returns it to my client. The URL essentially *can* contain a huge query string at the end. I prompt the user to open a download window with this URL, but sometimes it gets cut off (IE). Any ideal solutions or workarounds?

Comment: Queries should NEVER go in URLs in a plaintext state.  Use a POST variable if you can.

Comment: What version of IE?  Older versions limited urls to around 2k characters.  There is nothing to be done about that—it's hard coded.

Comment: @AaronLiske what do you mean by this? I make a post request and that request builds a URL that I need

Comment: @i_am_jorf IE 9 and 11 I believe. Currently testing on 11 and the path limit does seem to be ~2047

Comment: @xheyhenry, you said you have a URL that can contain a query.  That should never happen, where the query is editable through a URL

Comment: Are you using AJAX to send the request to the server? You should use the `POST` method, and put the parameters in the `send()` call, rather than putting them in the URL. URLs are limited by most clients and servers.

Comment: @Barmar yes I am using AJAX. I am already making a POST request to retrieve a built URL with some parameters, which is returned in its response

Comment: But your problem is with sending those received parameters to another URL. You need to used `POST` there, as well.

Comment: @Barmar hmm not sure I'm following. After I receive the URL I'm just calling a window.open(url)

Comment: That's just not going to work if `url` is too long. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: You need to come up with some other way of doing this, that doesn't require putting everything in the URL. Maybe use a session variable.

Comment: @Barmar yeah that was my problem - the url became too long for IE browsers. I'll look into those - thank you.

 Also, would specifying an HTTP header location with the URL work? or would it still encounter max url lengths?

Comment: @Barmar any suggestions on how to approach this? I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: I can't think of any way to solve this. A web page that requires a really long query parameter is just misdesigned.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. Still trying to wrap my head around how everything is working. This is also my first time working with query strings and I'm a novice when it comes to handling http requests